# How can I loop jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I've got a jQuery code which is supposed to change images after some amount of time and it works well, but it obviously stops as soon as the code ends. How can I make it run over and over again? I tried using javascript "if" loop but it didn't do anything.. or maybe I did it wrong?

(w4s and w5s are img's IDs)

Also I'm quite new to jQuery so if you have any comments about any errors I've made, I'd be glad to hear them!

Here's the code

```
$(function () { 
    $("#w4s").hide();
    $("#w5s").hide();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#w3s").delay("4000").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $("#w4s").fadeIn("slow",function () {
                    $(this).delay("4000").fadeOut("slow",function () {
                        $("#w5s").fadeIn("slow");
                    }); 
                });
             });
         });
    });    
});
```

Comment: "I tried using javascript "if" loop" - `if` isn't a loop, it's a conditional. `while`, `do while` and `for` are loops. Maybe try one of those if you want it to run over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need something like this

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  alert('I happen every 8 seconds');
   }, 8000);
```

Comment: Why -1? Stupid guys please go away

Comment: Thanks aefxx. I do think there is an abuse of down vote. It should be mandatory an explanation for it. It's my time that I decide to spend to help others so it should be rewarded. Down voting with no explanation get lost many people knowledge and that is a loss for all

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

```
$(document).ready(function() {...
```

is equivalent to

```
$(function() {...
```

so keep the latter and drop the usage of the former.

Second, understand what this invocation actually does: it tells jQuery to fire the callback (`function() {...`) once the DOM's ready. Therefore, you generally only need a single invocation of this pattern for all your code (unless you want different scopes, that is).

So, start your code like this in the outer most scope:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // Your code goes here !!!
  });
</script>
```

Now, since we've covered the basics, let's take care of your problem.

```
  $(function(){
    var looplength = 8000;
    // You can combine selectors!!!
    $("#w4s, #w5s").hide();

    // Let's drop all these nested `domready` callbacks and
    // in their stead set up an interval
    window.setInterval(function() {
      $("#w3s").delay("4000").fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $("#w4s").fadeIn("slow",function(){
          $(this).delay("4000").fadeOut("slow",function(){
            $("#w5s").fadeIn("slow");
          }); 
        });
      });
   }, looplength);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your advice. Really. It sounds sarcastic, but I really do :)  But the code still doesn't work. It just stops on "w4s" image and nothing happens. Am I supposed to somehow edit the code you gave me or should it run already? Maybe it's about my CSS or HTML.

Comment: If javascript "just stops" that's usually a good sign to check your browser's developer tools/console for errors and other messages. Press F12 :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a timeout for this - its probably just a personal preference, but I find them much more efficient than intervals, and it gives me more control over the continuation of the loop.

Something like this would do it:

```
//store the timer in your outer scope
var timer = null;

//create an empty elements var in your outer scope for use later
var elements;

//create a loop function do do most of your work for you
function loop(duration, index){

    //set the defaults if none are passed in
    duration = typeof duration == "number" ? duration : 8000;
    index = typeof index == "number" ? index : 0;

    //your function made a bit more generic
    //by selecting from the store elements list
    $(elements[index]).fadeOut("slow", function(){

        //Increase the index by 1 to select the next element,
        //or reset to 0 if it is greater than the number of elements you have
        index = index + 1 < elements.length ? index + 1 : 0;

        $(elements[index]).fadeIn("slow");
    });

    //clear the timeout in case it hasn't been called already
    clearTimeout(timer);

    //set the timeout function to call this function again
    // passing it back the index and duration
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        loop(duration, index)
    }, duration);
};

//Instantiate the loop function for the first time on document.ready
//It should continue on its own after that
$(document).ready(function() {
    //set the elements after the DOM is loaded
    elements = $("#w3s, #w4s, #w5s");
    loop(4000);
});
```

Hope this helps. It a fairly robust approach, so you could reuse this function elsewhere as well. If you need to cancel the loop at any point, you have it stored as `timer` so you can just call `clearTimeout('timer')` so long as you are in the same scope.

Fiddle available here - https://jsfiddle.net/heuw8dt0/2/

**EDIT:**
Moved element selection inside the DOM ready function

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work. As I open the page I just see the "#w5s" image and that's it. I've tried to read the code line by line and rewrite it to my html in order to understand it.. but it didn't work. CTRL C + CTRL V didn't help as well. Maybe it's about the way the images are stored in the html. I have no idea how to put code in the comment section, though

Comment: Sorry I'm not at my PC at the moment. I will put a fiddle together in the morning and post it up for you.

Comment: Ah managed to get to a PC :) it seems to be working in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/heuw8dt0/1/ - have a look in your console to see if you are getting any javascript errors or conflicts anywhere if this still doesn't help.

Comment: So after quite a long time I know what's the problem here. The code itself works great and I am very grateful about it, but for some reason it doesn't work when I put it into an external .js file. I'm 100% sure it's linked well (I've been trying using different codes in the same file and they worked.). As long as the code is put into html with <script>,</script> markers, it works well, but when I use <script src>, nothing happens. Any ideas? F12 console doesn't show any errors

Comment: It could be the point at which it is loading in - you could try moving the 'var elements' inside the document.ready function? I will update my answer to reflect this for you.

Comment: Yep, works perfectly now. Thanks, a lot. But why..? I mean, why moving these elements inside document.ready function made it work? Could u explain it? I owe you quite a huge beer for that anyway!

Comment: It will be because my original solution was selecting the elements before the DOM had loaded, meaning that they didn't exist yet. Therefore the loop would have been working, but just had no elements to fade in or out. That's my bad as I wasn't testing in a live environment :) glad it works now! Happy to help :)

Comment: No beer necessary - you can just mark me as correct of this works for you :)

Comment: I did, but I've got not enough respect and it seems like nobody cares about my opinion just yet :P